# Compare list with key from dict, if i from list = dict print value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, compare

Give a dict (`generate_translation_dict`) with triplets as keys and amino acids as values, I'd like to compare a list of triplets to the existing keys in that dictionary. If they equal each other, it should print the value.

For example:

```
generate_translation_dict = {'ATA': 'I',
  'ATC': 'I',
  'ATT': 'I',
  'ATG': 'M',
}
comparison_list = [ 
  'ATG',
  'TTT',
  'GTT',
]
```

If one of the items in list, for example 'ATG', is the same as a key from the dict, then it should print 'M'. The comparison list is imported from a text file and contains ~1200 items.

My code so far:

```
triplets = [] #This block imports the tripplets
with open('triplets.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip('\n') # um \n zu entfernen
        triplets.append(line)

aa = [] # aa for amino acids
with open('amino_acids.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip('\n') # um \n zu entfernen
        aa.append(line)

generate_translation_dict = {} # empty dictionary
for n in range(len(triplets)): 
    generate_translation_dict[triplets[n]] = aa[n] # adding elements to the dict # triplets added as keys/ aa added as value
print(generate_translation_dict)

tripletsequence = []
with open('triplet_sequence.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip('\n') # um \n zu entfernen
        tripletsequence.append(line)
```

As you can see, the tripletsequence is the list. The comparison should be a loop until the list is finished.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Make sure you read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions - Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service. Could you please post the exact problem you are having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the translation dict, all you need to do is iterate through `triplet_sequence` and use the triplets as keys in the dict.

You can also greatly simplify the creation of the translation dict by `zip`ping the two file streams and putting the result in a dict comprehension:

```
with open('triplets.txt') as triplets, open('amino_acids.txt') as aa:
    translation = {
        t.strip(): a.strip() 
        for t, a in zip(triplets, aa)
    }
with open('triplet_sequence.txt') as f:
    triplet_sequence = [
        translation[t.strip()]
        for t in f
    ]

print("\n".join(triplet_sequence))
```

```
% cat triplets.txt
ATA
ATC
ATT
ATG

% cat amino_acids.txt
I
I
I
M

% cat triplet_sequence.txt
ATG
ATT
ATC

% python test.py
M
I
I
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your translation dict in place (please check the last suggestion):

```
translation_dict = {
                    'ATA': 'I',
                    'ATC': 'I',
                    'ATT': 'I',
                    'ATG': 'M',
                    'TTT': 'P',
                    'GTT': 'V'
                  }
```

and the list with codons:

```
comparison_list = [ 
                    'ATG',
                    'TTT',
                    'GTT',
                  ]
```

You can decode to the sequence of amino-acids in this way:

```
seq = [translation_dict[k] for k in comparison_list]
print(seq) #=> ['M', 'P', 'V']
```

---

Using the [get()](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dict/get.html) method you can avoid errors for missing keys, if you find it a good idea (returns `None` as element in case of missing key):

```
seq = [translation_dict.get(k) for k in comparison_list]
```

or, removing `None` elements:

```
seq = list(filter(None, [translation_dict.get(k) for k in comparison_list]))
```

---

I'd suggest to store the translation dict as a **[JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) file** in order to load directly as a dict, ready for use.